# Timeline animation plays only one frame

Tags: animation, interface, timeline

When I play it, all frame loops in 0-1 frame.
What did I miss?

[image: blender timeline]

Comment: And, If I click middle of timeline, that green line stll stay in 0-1 frame

Answer (score 3):

You changed the [Time Remapping](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html#dimensions-panel). It is found in the lower right of the **Dimensions** section in the **Properties Panel**.
Make sure, the **Old** and **New** values are both the same, e. g. 100 and 100.

[image]

Comment: @ZaeMu If this was the solution, you should consider marking it as the accepted answer, by clicking the checkmark to the left.